# Have two excel cells equal the same thing?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I pretty sure you cannot do this in Excel but here it goes. Can you have say, "Cell 1" and "Cell 2" equal the same thing while both being editable?
So if i edit "Cell 1" it will change "Cell 2" and if I change "Cell 2" it will change "Cell 1". I keep running into the self-reference error, and was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Not with a formula, You can with vba by creating a Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score 1):

if VBA is not a choice then u can do this:

let Cell 1 (say A1) be the input cell

set Cell 2 = Cell 1 (i.e. say A2, in A2 type `=A1`)

to update A1, just type, its the input cell and A2 will update accordingly.

to update A2, select A2 and press `Ctrl+[`, excel will bring you to A1, then type into A1. After typing, to go back to A2, select A1 then press `Ctrl+]`.

if you are sharing the workbook with others, put a comment at A2 on how to manipulate the cell and warn user not to remove the formula.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use vba:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo here
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Me.Range("A2") = Target.value
ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    Me.Range("A1") = Target.value
End If

here:
End Sub
```

Comment: There should be a little more meat in this answer, but it does appear to attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - with VBA. Add this to your worksheet code, for example - it will "link" cells A1 and B1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    temp = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
       Me.Range("B1") = Target
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
       Me.Range("A1") = Target
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = temp
End Sub
```